# How do i run FuelPHP on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, fuelphp

Hi i have setup an app engine account. everything works ok with standard php. i have a local install of fuelphp, this works with no issues when running the development server of google app engine. however once i move it to the production application, i get an error stating the cache directory is unwritable of non existent. i read through some articles and it mentioned the application sandbox on GAE is not writable, so i went and manually change the configurations to point to an external path for the cache, the issues is this persist. i even tried to remove the usage of cache, ( false in config ) and hardcoded remove by commenting out. this just crashed everyting.

Comment: Is your external cache pointing to Google Cloud Storage?  This article might be helpful: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2014/01/15/php-app-engine-apps-and-file-system-concepts/

Answer (score 0):

## app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  FUEL_ENV: 'production'

handlers:
```

- url: /(.*.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
   static_files: public/\1
   upload: public/(.*.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
   application_readable: true
- url: /(.*.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: public/\1
   upload: public/(.*.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
   application_readable: true
- url: /assets
   static_dir: public/assets
- url: /favicon.ico
   static_files: public/favicon.ico
   upload: public/favicon.ico
- url: /.*
   script: public/index.php

Log file patch: https://github.com/isatan/FuelPHP4Gae_patch

Deploy SQL instance, load database schema and setup your production config.php to connect to in via unix socket.